# symfony datetime can't map to entity

Tags: symfony4

anyone have this strange problem？  it works right in my local computer, the datetime can map to my entity, but doesn't  in my production server, I write a functional test, same test data and same php version 7.1.25.

the json is following

```
{
    "ends_at": "2018-12-19 16:00:45",
    "starts_at": "2018-12-18 16:00:44",
    "state": "fulfilled",
    "units": {
        "18": {
            "ends_at": "2018-12-18 16:00:45",
            "starts_at": "2018-12-18 16:00:44",
            "state": "failed"
        }
    }
}
```

Both the TestType and TestUnitType have two datetime properties, startsAt and endsAt,

```
class TestType extends AbstractType
{
    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(ObjectManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('ends_at', FormType\DateTimeType::class, [
                'property_path'=> 'endsAt',
                'widget'=>'single_text',
                'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd H:i:s',
            ])
            ->add('starts_at', FormType\DateTimeType::class, [
                'property_path'=> 'startsAt',
                'widget'=>'single_text',
                'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd H:i:s',
            ])
            ->add('state', FormType\ChoiceType::class, [
                "choices" => [
                    'fulfilled' => 'fulfilled',
                    'running' => 'running',
                    'failed' => 'failed',
                    'ready' => 'ready',
                ],
            ])
            ->add('units', FormType\CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => TestUnitType::class,
                'allow_add'=> false,
                'allow_delete'=> false,
                'by_reference' => true
             ])
        ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Test::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you cleared Symfony cache?

Comment: Yep, I did， I clear it with command rm -rf var/cache